# How JavaScript for loop executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, execution, synchronous

The code after **for loop** is executing before the **for loop** on top. Javascript is executed synchronously, why it is executing line after for loop first?

```js
function solution(A) {
  let diff = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
    let sum1 = 0;
    let sum2 = 0;

    for (let j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
      sum1 += A[j];
      console.log('Why this is executing later? ' + sum1);
    }

    for (let k = i; k < A.length; k++) {
      sum2 += A[k];
    }

    console.log('Why this is executing frist? ' + sum1);
    diff.push(Math.abs(sum1 - sum2));
  }

  return Math.min(...diff);
}

solution([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time your outer loop runs, `i` will be `1`. Your inner loop checks if `j<i-1`, and `j` starts at `0`. So the first time your inner loop executes, it will check if `0 < 0`, which is false, and will immediately exit, and not perform the inner loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the code with your `Why this is executing later` message is not executed *at all* in the first run on the outer loop.

When you enter the first loop at `for(let i=1; i<A.length; i++){` `i` will be `1`.

Now you hit `for(let j=0; j<i-1; j++){` but `i-1` is `1-1` (because `i` is `1`) and so the loop will execute `0` times. And so `Why this is executing later` will not be executed.

So the next `console.log` message that will be executed is the one with `Why this is executing frist`.